# React Hooks : Custom hook from useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql

I'm calling a useCallback from a click event:

```
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={sendRequest}>
        Disable
      </Button>
```

And the useCallback function:

```
useCallback(() => {
     useQueryBlablablaAction(id);
  
  }, [id]);
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
React Hook "useQueryBlablablaAction" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.eslintreact-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

The `useQueryBlablablaAction` hook calls another hook to pass some params:

```
export function useQueryBlablablaAction(id) {
  return useGraphQLQuery(
    'blablablaAction',
    gql`
      mutation Mutation($ID: String!) {
        blablabla(Input: { ID: $ID }) {
          Status
        }
      }
    `,
    { ID: id }
  );
}
```

And the useGraphQLQuery

```
function useGraphQLQuery(
  name,
  query,
  variables = {}
){
  return useQuery(`bla${name}`, async () => {

    return request(endpoint, query, variables);
  });
}
```

I understand I cannot call the hook from the useCallback, but I'm not sure how to fix it ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The error is describing exactly what's going on. You're not calling the hook in a React hook, it's a callback

Comment: Can you share the `useQueryBlablablaAction` code? Can you also provide a bit more context around how you are trying to use it, or what you are trying/wanting to do?

Comment: @kevin I know, but I cannot find a way to solve it, any clues ?

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the post to include the hook

Comment: are you looking for `useLazyQuery` ? ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery